# Issue with Push Pins in windows phone Bing Map

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my application i am using Bing maps for locating cities. The issue is that when different items in my list contain the same city, the push pin get overlaps, resulting an improper output of the map view. This cause the marketplace submission failure. I searched for a solution in many sites but didn’t get any proper solution. Please anyone help men to find a solution.

Comment: Are you just getting the cityname? you're also getting coordinates, right? If they have the same coordinates, don't add them. if they don't, shouldn't the user just be able to zoom into the map more and there won't be collisions (i guess unless your coordinates were REALLY close...)

Comment: No i am only getting the country name, from that country name, i will find the geo cords by using googles geo code service. But in my case i am getting the same city name say "Austin" for many list items.

Answer (score 0):

> when different items in my list contain the same city

What does it mean ? Is the list contain two items with the exactly same name: item1="Paris" and item2="Paris" ? If so, try to change them more exactly location corresponding the real addresses, like: item1="Paris, bla bla street 6" and item2="Paris, another street 6"

Comment: yup its similar like 2 paris..But the issue is that i am oly getting "paris" as country details ... what i will do???